# compiling zthreads

Tags: c++, makefile

I downloaded zthreads (found here: http://zthread.sourceforge.net/) and tried to compile but I get this error from make:

```
MutexImpl.h:156: error: there are no arguments to 'ownerAcquired' that depend on a      template parameter, so a declaration of 'ownerAcquired' must be available
```

MutexImpl.h:156: error: (if you use '-fpermissive', G++ will accept your code, but allowing the use of an undeclared name is deprecated)

and then after that for every function in that source file I get this kind of error:

```
MutexImpl.h:167: error: there are no arguments to 'function' that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of 'function' must be available
```

So I'm guessing it's a makefile error but I'm not for sure how to tell make to tell g++ to compile the files with -fpermissive. Does anyone know how to put that into the makefile (if that is the problem)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CXXFLAGS += -fpermissive

Comment: I get the same error from g++ with that. In fact with that line I don't even see -fpermissive when make is displaying the opts g++ is using.

Comment: Checked it out with our heavily customized build system.
CXXFLAGS = -fpermissive $(CCFLAGS) $(INCLUDE_PATH) -D_PERF_TEST_
yielded

g++      -m64 -fpermissive -ggdb  -Wall -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-qual -m64 -D SUNOS -D INTEL -D _M64BIT_ -D _REENTRANT...

CXXFLAGS += -fpermissive also worked

Answer (score 2):

Standard gmake convention is to use the `CXXFLAGS` variable to pass options to the C++ compiler.  You can take advantage of that fact as well as a feature called "command-line overrides" to get your extra flag tacked onto the flags passed to g++ by invoking gmake this way:

```
make CXXFLAGS+=-fpermissive
```

I downloaded the source myself to verify that this works and found that it does, although there are still a bunch of other warnings emitted.  You may wish to log a bug for these issues if you intend to continue using the library.

Hope this helps,

Eric Melski

Answer (score 1):

I got rid of all these errors changing the code: for each line with that mistake, add this-> to the function that provokes the error. In the line you quote:

ownerAcquired must be changed by this->ownerAcquired

I hope this helps