# Error while compiling wxWidgets with TDM-GCC

Tags: wxwidgets

I've been trying to compile wxWidgets for a while now, I've been using TDM-GCC and have been following the guide [here](http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Compiling_wxWidgets_with_MinGW) with no such luck. The last few lines of my `mingw32-make -f makefile.gcc SHARED=1 UNICODE=1 BUILD=release MONOLITHIC=1` is

```
../../src/msw/thread.cpp: In member function 'void wxThread::Exit(wxThread::Exit
Code)':
../../src/msw/thread.cpp:1165:28: error: cast from 'wxThread::ExitCode {aka void
*}' to 'unsigned int' loses precision [-fpermissive]
     _endthreadex((unsigned)status);

makefile.gcc:4957: recipe for target 'gcc_mswudll\monodll_thread.o' failed
mingw32-make: *** [gcc_mswudll\monodll_thread.o] Error 1
```

Anyone got any ideas? Please help, I'm truly baffled.

Comment: That's not enough information, you omitted the line(s) with the actual error(s).

Comment: Downgrade the error to a warning.

See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/8843848/16582

Comment: Sorry, I must sound **really** stupid, but how do I get `mingw32-make` to pass this option to GCC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of @ravenspoint, and some googling, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724178/compiling-zthreads/724350#724350), which mentioned passing the variable `CXXFLAGS` to pass arguments to g++ (and for gcc, use `CFLAGS`), then from @ravenspoint's answer I added `CXXFLAGS+=-fpermissive` to my `mingw32-make -f makefile.gcc SHARED=1 UNICODE=1 BUILD=release MONOLITHIC=1`, to pass `-fpermissive` to g++.

Answer (score 0):

`{aka void*}` to `unsigned int` loses precision `[-fpermissive]`

That occurs when it expects 32 bit and gets a 64 bit, usually a problem in compiling code meant to be 32 bit in the TDM default -m64 bit mode.

For `void*` to lose precision, it must be a 64 bit variable, and `unsigned int` must be 32.

If you downgrade the variable by disabling the warning and run it on 64 bit machine, you could get a pointer error crash while running program.